# issue scrollto using fixed nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have built a one page site using scrollto and scrollspy. The page works great once the navbar gets fixed to the top. But if you click on any links before the navbar gets fixed to top all the links are off. And there is no consistency in the height that they are off.  I have played around with the offset, I do have a padding of 100px to each section to account for spacing issues.

Here is a link to the dev site... 
http://23.23.170.24/aspire/

Here is the js...

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop() +1; // the "12" should equal the margin-top value for nav.stick
    var div_top = $('#checkdiv').offset().top;
        if (window_top > div_top) {
           $('nav.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
            $('section').addClass('scrolled');
        } else {
             $('nav.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
              $('section').removeClass('scrolled');
        }
});


$(".click").click(function(evn){
      evn.preventDefault();
     $('html,body').stop(true).scrollTo((this.hash, this.hash),1000, {axis: 'y', offset   :0});
      return false;
});

$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#navbar' })
```

});

Answer (score 0):

When the header is *stuck*, Bootstrap `scrollspy` and `scrollto` are automatically taking into account the height of the header.  When *unstuck*, all you have to do is subtract the height of the header and you'll scroll to the correct spot on your page.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to write this out? Would I need a conditional statement to know when to subtract the height of the header?